# java - screenshot taken, but permission not granted?

Tags: java, permissions, screenshot

I am writing an application that needs to take screenshots of the users screen.
I am using the Robot class and the [createScreenCapture](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#createScreenCapture%28java.awt.Rectangle%29) method to achieve this.

As the Javadoc states, the `readDisplayPixels` permission is needed to take a screenshot.

I then went ahead and tried to check the permission before attempting to take a screenshot.
I prepared some code to show what I did:

```
import java.awt.AWTPermission;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class ScreenshotTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            new SecurityManager().checkPermission(new AWTPermission("readDisplayPixels"));
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            System.out.println("Permission not granted!");
        }

        try {
            Rectangle screenRect = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
            BufferedImage capture = new Robot().createScreenCapture(screenRect);
            System.out.println("Screenshot taken!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Taking screenshot failed.");
        }
    }
}
```

The console printout is:

```
Permission not granted!
Screenshot taken!
```

I am confused right now, because I did not expect that to happen. Shouldn't the `createScreenCapture` method throw an exception because the permission is not granted?

Comment: What is the stack trace of `SecurityException e` in the first `try/catch` block?

Comment: @Mateusz stack trace: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.awt.AWTPermission" "readDisplayPixels")
 at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
 at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
 at exp.ScreenshotTest.main(ScreenshotTest.java:12)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating some new `SecurityManager` instead of talking to the (maybe) existing one, so try this:

```
SecurityManager sm = System.getSecurityManager();
if (sm != null) {
    sm.checkPermission(new AWTPermission("readDisplayPixels"));
}
```

That is, if the VM has an instance of `SecurityManager`, you can communicate with it to check for the restriction, and if such an instance is absent - just perform any action you want to perform. Good luck with that!

P.S. You should never shadow stacktraces with your own messages unless they carry some useful information. In your case, you just hid some impotrtant info in favour of senseless messages. Don't do that.

And just in case I didn't make it clear - the exception in second `try-catch` block isn't thrown because internals of `Robot` do communicate with system's `SecurityManager`, while you were talking to some new instance, which hadn't had any useful payload. Here is the actual code from `Robot.java`:

```
public synchronized BufferedImage createScreenCapture(Rectangle screenRect) {
    checkScreenCaptureAllowed();
    //... proceed
}

private static void checkScreenCaptureAllowed() {
    SecurityManager security = System.getSecurityManager();
    if (security != null) {
        security.checkPermission(
            SecurityConstants.AWT.READ_DISPLAY_PIXELS_PERMISSION);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess that is the solution! I tried `System.getSecurityManager()` now and It returns null, so I just won't check for the permission. My initial though was, that these permissions are granted by the OS or JVM and that I could just check them. P.S.: Usually I do not handle exceptions like in the code above, this was just supposed to be an SSCCE to get my point across. edit: thanks for the code from Robot.java.

Comment: @greenkeeper, you are welcome. By the way, you could probably eliminate the first check at all by catching the corresponding `SecurityException` as a part of the `try` block where you take the screenshot.

Comment: Well, my actual code is a little more complicated than what I posted. In my application I start a new Thread where I take screenshots in a loop, that is why I want to check the permission before I start the Thread.

Answer (score 0):

You need to restructure your code, just a little:). You are close.

```
 try {
     new SecurityManager().checkPermission(new AWTPermission("readDisplayPixels"));
     Rectangle screenRect = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
     BufferedImage capture = new Robot().createScreenCapture(screenRect);
     System.out.println("Screenshot taken!");
 }  catch (SecurityException e) {
     System.out.println("Permission not granted!");
 }  catch (Exception e) {
     System.out.println("Taking screenshot failed.");
 }
```

When the first security exception is thrown, they will never get to the screen capture statements.

Hope that helps:)

Comment: in the question, they are separate try-catch blocks. Question is why isn't an exception thrown from the 2nd try-catch?

Comment: sorry, I may have been not clear enough. In the first code segment, I am explicitly checking if the `readDisplayPixels` permission is granted. In the second segment I am just taking the screenshot. If the permission was not granted in the first block, the second block should throw an exception too, because the javadoc for `createScreenCapture` states: `Throws SecurityException - if readDisplayPixels permission is not granted`.